# Typescript hinting + webstorm + nodejs + require

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm

So I decided it was time to up and learn typescript. I come from a .net background and am very proficient in NodeJS and want to merge the two.

I have hit a stump trying to use typescript with "require"d modules. I think a code example will illustrate better

```
///<reference path="tsd/q.d.ts" />
var q = require('q'); //<--- How do I set the type of this using the reference path above?
function test() {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I am aware of import but that seems to require the other file to be in typescript? OR am i completely misunderstanding what typescript can do?

Comment: It looks like the solution so far is that I need to use: import q = require('q'); which ties it up nicely. I also needed to ad --module commonjs arguments to my webstorm file watcher to allow it to compile

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to set `--module` to `commonjs` and use:

```
import q = require('q')
```

You will also need the `DefinitelyTyped` definition file for `q` (and `nodejs`) included in your build. Referencing it the way you did is possible, but if you use a build-integrated tool like WebStorm, Visual Studio or Atom, all the files in the project will be automatically included and the reference becomes non-required.

**TypeScript 1.5**:

From 1.5+ you will have a `tsconfig` file for the purpose of build order and inclusions, as is shown on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json. Set up your project file with include the typings as needed and you won't need to manually reference the files *everywhere*.

Comment: The purpose of the tsconfig is not for `.d.ts` references, if you specify them in the `files` list then those are the only files that will get compiled, I would suggest not using that to handle external references. That being said, if you use a tool like `tsd` it will handle organizing all your refs in one place and you would only need 1 reference for external modules. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd

Comment: The files listed are compiled in context with the other files. It works, you won't need silly references. It's essentially a project then.

Comment: Right, but anytime you add any file to the `project` then you will need to update the tsconfig.json I just prefer to have it pick up my files automatically based upon the directory structure, which reduces conflicts when committing/checking in code and is one less step for me to remember when a file is added which is more harmonious with node conventions

Comment: That's a valid point. Depending on your editor environment, however, the file references can be updated automatically. I use Atom with TypeStrong for this, it defines globs in the tsconfig files and automatically updates the references. This may be why I never need to think about it too much.